# How do make google drive authentication open up in a popup when using googleapis npm package?

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api, google-authentication

How do make google drive authentication open up in a popup when using googleapis npm package?

The current implementation that i have opens the sign in page in a new tab i want it to open in a popup. After reading the documentation the doc https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#googleauthsigninoptions says to use "ux_mode": popup while doing init, but i am not sure how to do it while using the google apis npm package!

Comment: Oauth2 consent window should always open in a new browser window on the users machine.

Comment: Please add the steps to reproduce you issue accurately.

Comment: @Aerials as @DalmTo mentioned if Oauth2 consent window should always open in a new browser window then the only solution is to make the window open up as a popup using `window.open(url, title, optionsString)` where `optionsString` can define the width and height of the window. This is what i am going with, let me know if there is a better approach.

Comment: I did not understand that you where building the pop up screen yourself. I thought you were using Google's OAuth Flow and Google generates that screen in a pop up for you.

Comment: @Aerials Google's oAuth Flow always opens it in a new browser window and Google is generating it for me. I am just resizing the window to make it look like a popup.